# applications sometimes keeps bouncing, won't open and won't respond to force quit

Tags: mac

Most of the time my macbook air works fine. Only problem is that when I just turned on my pc and want to open some applications , often these applications won't open and force quit does not work. Currently, I just wait a couple of minutes and then everything works just fine, but actually I don't want to wait, so I was wondering how to solve this problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the types of devices, OS, etc.  Also let us know what you've already done to solve the problem yourself.  Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered. - From Review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try nvram reset
If didnt help
Reinstall those apps 
Worked for me